# issue in VS.2017 and crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS 2017 and Crystal Reports, but the issue is it won't load:

[image]

Comment: Please post the error here also.

Comment: what was in the activity log mentioned in the screenshot? There's not really enough info here for anyone to help I don't think.